# Using python and re.findall, I'm trying to count the number of valid domain hits in an apache log

Tags: python, regex, apache, findall, logfile

This is an example of a 'valid' line in my log file:
`194.81.31.125 - - [129/Dec/2013:22:03:09 -0500] "GET http://www.firemaiden.hu/cgi-bin/top/topsites.cgi?an12 HTTP/1.0" 200 558 "http://Afrique" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)"`

I've got this re.findall expression: `(GET|POST)\s(http://|https//)[a-zA-Z]+.+?"\s200`
This expression contains all the rules for a valid line, but doesn't extract the domain.

I want to count the top-level domains, in this case "hu", for each date and dump the count for each domain into an organized log file.  I also want to extract the non-valid lines into a different log file

output ideally is:

`12/Dec/2013[tab]as:1[tab]ab:2[tab]hu:4`

`13/Dec/2013[tab]as:4[tab]br:7[tab]cd:8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't extract the domain; you didn't put that in a capturing group by wrapping it in parentheses.

So, the first thing to do is to add the parentheses:

```
r'(GET|POST)\s(http://|https//)([a-zA-Z]+.+?)"\s200'
```

But that's still not right, as it will capture the entire `www.firemaiden.hu/cgi-bin/top/topsites.cgi?an12 HTTP/1.0`, not just the `www.firemaiden.hu`. That's because you only have one group of letters followed by anything at all up to a quote. You want just letters and dots (which isn't actually correct for DNS, but let's ignore that for the moment). Like this:

```
r'(GET|POST)\s(http://|https//)([a-zA-Z\.]+).+?"\s200'
```

And now you get `www.firemaiden.hu`.

But you wanted just the `.hu`, right? So, what you really need as many letters and dots as possible up to a group of just letters after a dot:

```
r'(GET|POST)\s(http://|https//)[a-zA-Z\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]+).+?"\s200'
```

However, you will want to read the rules on DNS names—which are actually up to each root server, in theory. But anything under the standard world roots follows the LDH rule: letters, digits, hyphens. So, you want `[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]`, right?

But many servers will also accept underscores and treat them as hyphens, and some servers will decode [IDNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) ([punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)) names to Unicode for logging, so even that may not be right.

All that being said, I think that, rather than use a regexp you didn't know how to write and may not understand, you go with a simpler regexp to get just the URL (which you already know how to do), and then use a dedicated URL parser to crack it:

```
r'(GET|POST)\s(\S+)\s.*?200'
```

Then:

```
p = urllib.parse.urlparse(match[1])
```

Now `p.scheme` is your `'http'` or `'https'`, `p.netloc` is `'www.firemaiden.hu'` (which you can easily call `.split('.')[-1]` on), etc.

Comment: Thanks for that info...I am curious how to resolve the situation where the domain server is located after just one '.'  for example: `http://firemaiden.com`

Comment: @kegewe: What do you mean "how to resolve the situation"? Have you tried any of my examples? Both of them give you `com` for that URL. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, instead of using urllib, I tried your first suggested modification of the regex expression and I was able to pull the domain as the third element of the tuple output. Now I just need to organize the output.

Comment: @kegewe: Which one? The first two don't work at all, as explained in the answer. The third one, the one that works for `www.firemaiden.hu`, also works for `firemaiden.com`. So, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: It seems that the third one is also returning some values that aren't top-level domains.  For example, it is returning a word like 'southern' in the address www.southern-charms.com

Comment: Ideally the top-level domains would be the first instance of `.domain/` that comes after `http` or `https`

Comment: @kegewe: First, I already explained why your `[a-zA-Z]` doesn't actually work for real domain names because it's the wrong rule. Please read the answer. As for the second… if you want to search for `\.(tld)/`, you can do that instead, but it won't give you anything different than searching for `[more\.components\.]sld\.(tld)`.

Comment: I just thought I might be able to search for the specific bit of text that comes after at least 1 '.' and is right before the first'/'

Comment: @kegewe: Yes, you can, just as you can search for the specific bit of text that comes after the last `.` in a sequence of valid DNS characters, and you will get the exact same thing either way.